# "error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: TypeError: cannot read property 'getFullyQualifiedIdentifier' of null)",

Tags: access-control, hyperledger-composer

I am getting below error while following tutorial here.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/managing/current-participant.html

I have created one Participant and issued identity to it. But in my transaction processor function,when I verify the participant ID of the current participant by using the getCurrentParticipant function through rest apis I get below error.

{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    **"message": "error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: TypeError: cannot read property 'getFullyQualifiedIdentifier' of null)",**
    "stack": "Error: error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: TypeError: cannot read property 'getFullyQualifiedIdentifier' of null)\n    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/praval/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:847:34)"
  }
}

Can anybody explain the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the mapping from certificate to participant is not in place. The easiest way to test this is to use the `composer identity issue` command and then use `composer network ping` -- which will return the current participant. Once that is working then `getCurrentParticipant()` should work.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/identity-issue.html

When you `composer network ping` your participant will try to access the network metadata. The ACL rule below will permit this access. Please ensure that you are using the latest version of the basic-sample-network which includes this rule.

```
rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. But while running ping commnad it gives below error. 
composer network ping -n 'basic-sample-network' -i parth -s pAAqPGvWVdoP

Error: error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Participant 'org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant#parth' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#basic-sample-network@0.1.1')

Comment: Interesting, that is the ACL engine restricting access to the network metadata itself to your participant. To open that up you can edit the ACL file in your network. See answer for details.

Comment: I am using belwo acl file.. It seems fine with me.                                   
 rule AllAccess {
  description: "AllAccess - grant everything to everybody"
  participant: "org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.acme.sample.**"
  action: ALLOW
}

Comment: I imported the .bna file in composer playground. Getting the same error while submitting a transaction.

Comment: Please describe your exact steps and where this BNA file came from. You *must* use the latest version of this file. E.g. load the latest basic-sample-network into Playground (using Import/Replace and selecting the sample using the radio button) and then exporting it from Playground.

Comment: Hi Dan. I am able to run composer ping command successfully. But I still get the null error for getCurrentParticipant(). Can you please help?

Comment: What was the output from ping? Did it list your participant id?

Comment: Yes. It listed participant id.                                                            
 composer network ping -n 'basic-sample-network' -i parth -s gCaebtiDeSTn

The connection to the network was successfully tested: basic-sample-network
 version: 0.10.0
 participant: org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant#parth

Command succeeded

Comment: Can you include the code you use to connect to the network. Are you sure you are using the right enrollmentId when you connect? I.e. the same info you used for ping.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using admin credentials while deploying code to rest-server instead of user. Thank you so much Dan for the help.